# React App not loading in IE11 in windows server

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, internet-explorer-11

I am a novice in React and developed a utility application and it's working fine in local machine.

I tried to deploy build folder in IIS on Windows server but when I am trying to access it in IE, I am getting blank page after some time. Below is the error I can see in the console:

[image]

Debugger is showing this:

[image]

Below are the dependencies in my package.json:

[image]

Regards,

Comment: Are you explicitly required to support IE 11? If not then this is not a real problem

Comment: (because it's past end of life. MS no longer maintains or supports it. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/internet-explorer-11 for details)

Comment: as of now it's ie11 only, will check the feasibility if I can get chrome installed on the server and then will check.

Comment: Why chrome? the current MS browser is Edge. You already have it, it comes with Windows.

Comment: If it's a website you can presumably access it via a locally installed chrome via its IP address or hostname without needing to install anything on the remote server. Though this may require you to expose the website to the internet

Comment: @apokryfos yeah it's internal server so accessible from local. It's working with chrome on local. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

React 18 does not support Internet Explorer. Drop back to React 17 if you need to support that (note that IE is end-of-life though).

https://reactjs.org/blog/2022/03/08/react-18-upgrade-guide.html#dropping-support-for-internet-explorer

Even with React 17, you'll likely need polyfills, such as [react-app-polyfill](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/main/packages/react-app-polyfill/README.md).

Answer (score -1):

Symbols are a "new" javascript concept that isn't supported in IE11.

You'll need to eject and change your target in your compiler so it transpires this to something IE11 can interpret.

Comment: can you please help how to do that ?

Comment: I answered your question. You can research more on the subject.

Comment: Or, you can simply not support IE11.